# Setting a minimum width to fit on responsive website

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm making a fully responsive website but it's really handy to have a min-height of the site set to 480px, instead of "industry standard" 320px. I know meta tag viewport and this pretty much does the job for me on smallest screens:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480, user-scalable=no">
```

But this works only for a mobile, any device with screen reporting more than 480px isn't scaled properly. For these, this one works:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Is there please a way how to combine both these? Somehow set smallest possible width of the site with no regards to the actual screen size but use any higher value of screen that 480px.

Thanks a lot, Jakub

Comment: So you want the smallest width of the site to be 480, and above that to be whatever the viewport size is?

Comment: Could you not use css? There are some simple two line tricks in css to get proper scalability depending on browser window size.

Comment: Josh Rutherford: Exactly :).
Kyle: It can be either CSS or jQuery or anything else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the latter meta viewport value and simply set the [min-width CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width) for the body or your container element to be the 480px value you require and set the [width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) to 100%. The min-width will override the width value (as you would expect) when the 100% width falls below 480px.

I'd strongly recommend that you set [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing): border-box so you can add padding to your body or container without exceeding the total 100% screen width.

Please also note that disabling user scaling ("user-scalable=no") is poor user experience for many users, and in particular for those with accessibility needs. I'd suggest you set initial-scale=1 instead. See http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/

The final result should look something like this-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

CSS-

```
#container {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   min-width: 480px;
   padding: 20px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hello,
thanks, this works fine with only one exception. Phone (at least Android) loads the site in 480px but not resized so the part of site is actually missing on the right. When you downsize it manually to the smallest size, it looks awesome, but not automatically. Is there any way how to load it downsized all the time?

Comment: + screens, this is how it loads [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uhb2af1q1ldloa2/2014-04-09%2010.38.35.png) and this is how it how it should load [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f2z4k3tylecptpg/2014-04-09%2009.55.14.png)

Comment: This very much depends how you have done your layout. Float based or Flexbox (often developers combine both) is best, table layouts or absolute positioning is a no-go. Widths should be percent based (you may wish to use media queries to adapt these as you transition between narrow and wider viewport sizes). Is there a live link and/or JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) of the layout/outline that we could look at? Primary check you can do yourself is that all elements use percents and not explicit widths (it helps to know standard element wrapping behaviour). Max-width is useful for images etc.

Comment: @Machi Do you still require help with this? If so, please can you provide some details on your layout and I will try and update the answer over the weekend. Otherwise, if one of these answers has helped you please accept it to help future users with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

This will limit the mobile version to 520px;

```
<meta name="viewport" id="vp" content="user-scalable=no, width=520, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5">
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        if (screen.width > 520) {
            var mvp = document.getElementById('vp');
            //mvp.setAttribute('content','');
            mvp.setAttribute('content','width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure about the answer with container min-width, because Chrome mobile preview not understands it. Adding this hack(jQuery used):

```
jQuery(function($){
    let upgradeViewport = function(){
        let viewport = $('meta[name=viewport]');
        let viewportMinWidth = parseInt($('head').attr('data-viewport-width'));
        if (viewport.attr('content').indexOf('user-scalable=0')!=-1 || viewport.attr('content').indexOf('user-scalable=no')!=-1){
            return;
        }
        if (!upgradeViewport.original) upgradeViewport.original = viewport.attr('content');

        if(window.innerWidth <= viewportMinWidth) {
            viewport.attr('content', 'width='+viewportMinWidth);
        }else{
            viewport.attr('content', upgradeViewport.original);
        }
    };
    $(document).ready(upgradeViewport);
    $(window).resize(upgradeViewport);
});
```

will dynamicly change viewport meta tag by the value in attribute `data-viewport-width` of `head` . Working fine, also with mobile-previewers.

Answer (score -3):

First thing it is better to go with  % rather than fixing the width=480px.(Example:- min-width: 45%). And the screen will automatically adjust itself based on the screen resolution.